# Packets getting dropped after clearing rp_filter

Tags: networking, iptables

I see certain packets in tcpdump and not able to trace whats happening to them. 
I did set `rp_filter to 0` and `log_martians to 1` on all interfaces. 
I enabled traces in iptables as well.

```
root@sindhu# iptables --list-rules -t raw
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -j TRACE
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -j TRACE
```

Still I see no trace belonging to the packet I see in tcpdump. 
I created a specific rule for those packets in iptables, but the count on that rule is not getting incremented. Is there something that I'm missing? I've been debugging this for 2 days. Any help would be really appreciated.

Edit:
Adding more details as requested.

Tcpdump:

```
03:01:07.625357 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 6637, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.103.1.33950 > 192.168.100.100.81: Flags [S], cksum 0x29b9 (correct), seq 2582058365, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4467432 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
03:01:07.625362 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 41508, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.103.1.33951 > 192.168.100.100.81: Flags [S], cksum 0x7ddb (correct), seq 2897653386, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4467432 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Iptables:

```
# iptables --list -vxn 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1278 packets, 102705 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:81

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 42 packets, 2520 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 779 packets, 104083 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

# iptables --list -vxn -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 420 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:81

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:81

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 37 packets, 2306 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 17 packets, 1146 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
      48     3072 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      vEth0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

# iptables --list -vxn -t raw
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1491 packets, 119478 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:81
    2088   169549 TRACE      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 891 packets, 117135 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1236   169357 TRACE      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

As can be seen all the input/prerouting rules specific to dport 81 have 0 packet counts.

Other settings:

```
# sysctl -a | grep \\.rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.vEth0.rp_filter = 0

# sysctl -a| grep martians
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
```

The packet is destined to a local webserver running on port 81.

```
# netstat -at | grep 81
tcp        0      0 *:81                    *:*                     LISTEN
```

The destination address of the packet, 192.168.100.100 is the address of vEth0 on the machine.

```
root@cfae:/opt/pep/filesystem# ifconfig vEth0
vEth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0e:c9:59:d9:75:ce  
          inet addr:192.168.100.100  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
# ip route get 192.168.100.100 from 192.168.103.1 iif vEth0
local 192.168.100.100 from 192.168.103.1 dev lo  src 192.168.100.100 
    cache <local>  iif vEth0
```

Comment: Can you tell us more? Can you show us examples of the tcpdump capture? Can you show us the specific rule for those packets?

Comment: I Found the issue, the ethernet frame was bad (in the sense that dest mac address was not vEth0 mac address). I didn't realize tcpdump sniffs packets even before layer 2 processing.

Comment: Post it as an answer and accept it. Then readers will know this one is solved / answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the issue, the ethernet frame was bad (in the sense that dest mac address was not vEth0 mac address). I didn't realize tcpdump sniffs packets even before layer 2 processing.